# Randomize output

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I have a page where I output item details. The data is stored in db and I use foreach to echo it on the page. Currently the items appear in the order they are stored in my table. What is the best way to randomize the order the items appear on the page every time it loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bool **shuffle** ( array *&$array* )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array.
Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
    $set[] = $row;
    }

shuffle($set); // rows now in random order

foreach ($set as $row)
    {
    echo $row['column'];
    }
```

Comment: This requires storing all the database results within array, correct? Just asking, maybe you know the way results can skip storing in array and be read when needeed for displaying.

Comment: @Tadeck All the results you _selected with your query_, yes. Since you're displaying that set of records, they're all "needed". I don't really get your question.

Comment: Ok, so the point is that using eg. [mysql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), you just get one row each time you use this function. In case of your solution all the results have to be fetched into the array and they are shuffled. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @Tadeck: Added an example; If there was any confusion before, that should clear it up.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you can do a `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT n`

But i can become slow on for large tables, because it will need to sort the entire table before returning the top *n* results.

Adding a `WHERE RAND() < 0.1` will speed up the query because it wil only need to sort ~10% of the table.

Comment: +1 This is the best way as does not require you to get them all first and then shuffle on application side. This way you are still able to fetch each record separately, when needed.

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() is reeeeeeaally slow. In case you have a decent amount of rows, ORDER BY RAND() is not a real option.

Comment: @yes123 You could always *favorite* the question. ;-)

Comment: I understood the question as first selecting a specific set of items from the database, _then_ displaying them in random order. This selects a _random set_ of items. The question says he `foreach`es them, therefore they must already be in an array.

Comment: @Core Xii You're right. I use a class that I use to query my db and indeed the results are all returned in an array. I really like this mySQL suggestion but in this particular case it will be a lot easier and more practical to use shuffle()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing it right away, I'd store the data in an array, and then randomize the content of the array using [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). With the second argument of this function, you can specify how many items you want to randomly pick.